# How to create a Decryption From this Encryption

Tags: assembly, encryption, x86, reverse-engineering

So I've got this assignment where I have to create a decrypt function using the "encrpypt_chars" function as a bases. From my understanding the code takes the length of a string and a encryption key then uses that encryption key to manipulate each value individually in the string which is stored in:

```
temp_char = OChars[i];              // Get the next char from Original Chars array
```

My goal is to a similar thing for the decryption routine but reverse so that I get the Ecrypted string back to its original values.

```
void encrypt_chars (int length, char EKey)
{
  char temp_char;                       // Character temporary store

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)      // Encrypt characters one at a time
  {
    temp_char = OChars[i];              // Get the next char from Original Chars array
    __asm
    {                                   
        push   eax                      // stores the "eax" register out onto the stack
        push   ecx                      // stores the "ecx" register out onto the stack
        push   edx                      // stores the "edx" register out onto the stack

        movzx  ecx, temp_char           // zeroise "ecx" register and move values in "temp_char" varaible to "ecx" register
        lea    eax, EKey                // copies address of values contained within the EKey varaible and moves it into "eax"register

        push eax                        // stores the "eax" register out onto the stack
        push ecx                        // stores the "ecx" register out onto the stack

        call   encrypt_5                // runs the function called "decryptX"
        mov    temp_char, dl            // move values in "dl" register into "temp_char" variable

        add esp, 8                      // add 8 to the "esp" register
        pop    edx                      // removes the "edx" register from the stack
        pop    ecx                      // removes the "ecx" register from the stack
        pop    eax                      // removes the "eax" register from the stack
    }
    EChars[i] = temp_char;              // Store encrypted char in the Encrypted Chars array
  }
  return;

            // Inputs: register EAX = 32-bit address of Ekey,
            //                  ECX = the character to be encrypted 
            //                  (in the low 8-bit field, CL).

            // Output: register EDX = the encrypted value of the source character 
            //                        (in the low 8-bit field, DL).

  __asm
  {
  encrypt_5:
        push  ebp                       // stores the pointer onto the stack
                                        //
        mov   ebp, esp                  // move values in "esp" register into "ebp" register
        mov   eax, [ebp + 12]           // take value from the stack that is 8 bits above
                                        // from the pointer a putting it in the "eax" register
        mov   ecx, [ebp + 8]            // take value from the stack that is 8 bits above 
                                        // from the pointer a putting it on ecx
        push  eax                       // stores the Ekey address onto the stack
        mov   al, byte ptr[eax]         // move the pointer of the eax register to the al register in bytes
        push  ecx                       // move the encrytped charcter value on the stack
        and   eax, 0x7C                 // and eax with 0x7c (1111100 in binary)
        ror   eax, 1                    // Rorate eax register value right by 1 byte shift
        not eax                         // not the eax values within the eax register
        ror   eax, 1                    // Rotate eax register value right by 1 byte shift
        inc   eax                       // increase the byte value of eax by 1
        mov   edx, eax                  // moves the values within eax to edx
        pop   ecx                       // removes ecx from the stack
        pop   eax                       // removes eax from the stack
        mov   byte ptr[eax], dl         // move dl to the pointer of the eax register in bytes 
        xor   edx, ecx                  // Exclusive or ecx with edx and stores the value with edx
        rol   dl, 1                     // Rotate dl register value left by 1 byte shift
        pop   ebp                       // returning ebp back to the orginal value
        ret                             // end function
  }

  //--- End of Assembly code
}
//*** end of encrypt_chars function
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------




//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------- DECRYPTION ROUTINES -------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
void decrypt_chars (int length, char EKey)
{
    char temp_char;                       // Character temporary store

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)      // Encrypt characters one at a time
    {
        temp_char = EChars[i];              // Get the next char from Original Chars array
        __asm
        {
            push   eax                      // stores the "eax" register out onto the stack
            push   ecx                      // stores the "ecx" register out onto the stack
            push   edx                      // stores the "edx" register out onto the stack

            movzx  ecx, temp_char           // zeroise "ecx" register and move values in "temp_char" varaible to "ecx" register
            lea    eax, EKey                // copies address of values contained within the EKey varaible and moves it into "eax"register

            push eax                        // stores the "eax" register out onto the stack
            push ecx                        // stores the "ecx" register out onto the stack

            call   decrypt_5                // runs the function called "decryptX"
            mov    temp_char, dl            // move values in "dl" register into "temp_char" variable

            add esp, 8                      // add 8 to the "esp" register
            pop    edx                      // removes the "edx" register from the stack
            pop    ecx                      // removes the "ecx" register from the stack
            pop    eax                      // removes the "eax" register from the stack
        }
        DChars[i] = temp_char;              // Store encrypted char in the Encrypted Chars array
    }
    return;

    // Inputs: register EAX = 32-bit address of Ekey,
    //                  ECX = the character to be encrypted 
    //                  (in the low 8-bit field, CL).

    // Output: register EDX = the encrypted value of the source character 
    //                        (in the low 8-bit field, DL).

    __asm
    {
    decrypt_5:
            push  ebp                       // stores the pointer onto the stack
                                            //
            mov   ebp, esp                  // move values in "esp" register into "ebp" register
            mov   eax, [ebp + 12]           // take value from the stack that is 8 bits above
                                            // from the pointer a putting it in the "eax" register
            mov   ecx, [ebp + 8]            // take value from the stack that is 8 bits above 
                                            // from the pointer a putting it on ecx
            push  eax                       // stores the Ekey address onto the stack
            mov   al, byte ptr[eax]         // move the pointer of the eax register to the al register in bytes
            push  ecx                       // move the encrytped charcter value on the stack

            and   eax, 0x7C                 // and eax with 0x7c (1111100 in binary)
            ror   eax, 1                    // Rorate eax register value right by 1 byte shift
            not   eax                       // not the eax values within the eax register
            ror   eax, 1                    // Rotate eax register value right by 1 byte shift
            inc   eax                       // increase the byte value of eax by 1

            mov   edx, eax                  // moves the values within eax to edx
            pop   ecx                       // removes ecx from the stack
            pop   eax                       // removes eax from the stack
            mov   byte ptr[eax], dl         // move dl to the pointer of the eax register in bytes 
            xor   edx, ecx                  // Exclusive or ecx with edx and stores the value with edx
            rol   dl, 1                     // Rotate dl register value left by 1 byte shift
            pop   ebp                       // returning ebp back to the orginal value
            ret                             // end function
    }

    //--- End of Assembly code
}

//*** end of decrypt_chars function
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have a feeling that the answer is to do with this part and "reversing" it in some way since this the the only part in which changes the Ekey:

```
            and   eax, 0x7C                 // and eax with 0x7c (1111100 in binary)
            ror   eax, 1                    // Rorate eax register value right by 1 byte shift
            not   eax                       // not the eax values within the eax register
            ror   eax, 1                    // Rotate eax register value right by 1 byte shift
            inc   eax                       // increase the byte value of eax by 1
```

Please help me figure this out.

Comment: *Rotate eax register value right by 1 byte shift*.  Nope, it's only 1 bit of the 32-bit register, not a whole byte.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60787907/x86-assembly-encryption-to-decryption and the same in that the only part to modify is `xor   edx, ecx` \ `rol   dl, 1`. Try `ror cl, 1` \ `xor dl, cl` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to my answer to [x86 assembly encryption to decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60787907/x86-assembly-encryption-to-decryption/60792360#60792360). I updated the repo with [another revision](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/testcode/rev/ebf6189ec222) which replaces their `encrypt_3` and `decrypt_3` with your `encrypt_5` and `decrypt_5`. Here's the specific part of `encrypt_5` that is actually relevant:

```
        mov   byte [eax], dl
        xor   edx, ecx
        rol   dl, 1
```

Here's the reverse part in `decrypt_5`. As for the linked answer, the key byte calculation stays exactly the same. (You misidentified the key byte calculation as the part to reverse, when it should be the application of the key byte to the plaintext byte.)

```
        mov   byte [eax], dl
        ror cl, 1
        xor   edx, ecx
```

(As only the low byte is used, `xor dl, cl` is a valid replacement for the `xor` line.)